# php display only duplicate value from array (facebook api)

Tags: php, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want delete duplicate post from array of facebook graph data

my page data like :

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "link": "http://example.com/188",
         "id": "427801497327797_428375477270399",
         "created_time": "2013-06-29T14:16:26+0000"
      },
      {
         "link": "http://example.com/188",
         "id": "427801497327797_428375187270428",
         "created_time": "2013-06-29T14:15:27+0000"
      },
      {
         "link": "http://example.com/188",
         "id": "427801497327797_428363873938226",
         "created_time": "2013-06-29T13:33:17+0000"
      },
      {
         "link": "http://example.com/196",
         "id": "427801497327797_428363597271587",
         "created_time": "2013-06-29T13:32:07+0000"
      }
   ],
   "paging": {
      "previous": "",
      "next": ""
   }
}
```

You can see duplicate link `example.com/188`.
I want get id of all duplicate link.
I'm working with [facebook-page-poster](https://github.com/keeganstreet/facebook-page-poster)

Comment: Do not post only what you want. Add some code to demonstrate what have you tried to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your concern is to remove duplicate link data then you can do like this

```
<?php
$duplicate_ids = array();
$all_links = array();
$facebook_data = array(
    'data' => array(
        array(
            'link' => 'http=>//site.com/188',
            'id' => '427801497327797_428375477270399',
            'created_time' => '2013-06-29T14=>16=>26+0000'
        ), array(
            'link' => 'http=>//site.com/188',
            'id' => '427801497327797_428375187270428',
            'created_time' => '2013-06-29T14=>15=>27+0000'
        ), array(
            'link' => 'http=>//site.com/188',
            'id' => '427801497327797_428363873938226',
            'created_time' => '2013-06-29T13=>33=>17+0000'
        ), array(
            'link' => 'http=>//site.com/196',
            'id' => '427801497327797_428363597271587',
            'created_time' => '2013-06-29T13=>32=>07+0000'
        )
    ),
    'paging' => array(
        'previous' => '',
        'next' => ''
    )
);
$data_count = count($facebook_data['data']);
for ($i = 0; $i < $data_count; $i++) {
    if (in_array($facebook_data['data'][$i]['link'], $all_links)) {
        $duplicate_ids[] = $facebook_data['data'][$i]['id'];
        unset($facebook_data['data'][$i]);
    } else {
        $all_links[] = $facebook_data['data'][$i]['link'];
    }
}

echo '<pre>'; print_r($duplicate_ids); '</pre>';
```

Comment: why are you decrementing `$data_count`? It won't iterate through whole array and may leave some duplicates at the end.

Comment: because array length/count will decrement on every `unset($facebook_data['data'][$i]);`

Comment: :D You killed me with this reasoning. Of course you are right, array length will decrease, but index association won't be changed. you can unset element `$data[5]` but `$data[6]` will still be there, waiting to be iterated over.

Comment: @manoj.admlab thanks for your help but i need get only duplicate links

Comment: @dev-null-dweller  Thanks for correcting me. I thought index association will change. I have removed `$data_count--;` from above code.

Comment: @user2535061 I have updated above code to get duplicate ids as you described in OP